# Formulate sudoku puzzle given the solutions

Tags: java, sudoku, backtracking

I just recently did a sudoku solver in java using backtracking.

Is it possible, given the solutions, to formulate a problem or puzzle?

**EDIT**

to formulate the original puzzle, is there some way to achieve this?

and an additional question,

given the puzzle and the solutions.

If I am able to solve the puzzle using the solutions (result is puzzles)

and at the same time able to solve the solutions using the puzzle (result is solutions)

Which has the greater number?

the puzzles? or the solutions?

Comment: Don't know exactly, but you'll probably need more restrictions. There are definitly more "start - states" which result in the same solution, which means that getting the original from a solution has more possible answers. For instance, when i clear just one field I have 9*9=81 "original" puzzles resulting in the same solution.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part. (I'm not english, sorry) Could you clarify it please ?

Comment: What would be greater in number, the formulated puzzles? or the formulated solutions?

Comment: @Heru-Luin, JohannisK was illustrating his observation that there is a large number of distinct Sudoku puzzles that yield the same solution. He pointed out that for any solved Sudoku grid, there are 81 distinct starting puzzles with 80 filled cells that yield that solution (counting the solution itself as a trivial puzzle).  The number explodes from there.  In fact, for any given Sudoku solution, there are exactly 2^81 starting Sudoku puzzles that afford that solution (not necessarily uniquely).

Comment: A good puzzle has only one solution, but it's trivial to show there are tons of puzzles that yield the same solution. So the numbers of solution from a puzzle is larger than the number of puzzles you find from a solution. If instead, you allow puzzles that have multiple solutions, then on average the number of puzzles per solution is equal to the number of solution per puzzles. After all, if a solution has a puzzle, that very same puzzle also has the said solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to formulate **one of the multiple possible** original states.

1. Start with the final solution (all numbers are present)
2. Remove one number (chosen randomly or not)
3. Check if this number can be found back given the current state of the board (you already have a solver, it should be easy)
4. If this number can be calculated, everything is OK. Go back to 2.
5. If this number cannot be found back, put it back where it was. Go back to 2.

If no more numbers can be removed, you have reached one of the original states of the puzzle.

If you chose the numbers you remove randomly (step 2), you can execute this several times, and get different starting points that lead to the same final puzzle.

Comment: What if you have let us say 1000 solutions to the original puzzle. how can you formulate the original puzzle?

Comment: You will not be able to find one specific original state of the board.
As several starting states lead to one final state, it is impossible to guess exactly which starting state is the one you had if you only know the final state of the puzzle.

Comment: Can you share your insight regarding the additional question too?

Answer (score 0):

> If I am able to solve the puzzle using the solutions (result is puzzles)
>   and at the same time able to solve the solutions using the puzzle (result is solutions)
>
> Which has the greater number?
>
> the puzzles? or the solutions?

There is no well-defined answer.

Each solution has exactly 2<sup>81</sup> corresponding puzzles, including the trivial one.  Not all of these have a unique solution, but many do.  Therefore, if the chosen set of solutions contains only one element, then the maximal set of puzzles that jointly correspond to the solution set is vastly larger.

On the other hand, [the completely blank puzzle affords 6670903752021072936960 solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku).  There are many pairs of those that share only the blank grid as a common puzzle.  Thus, if the chosen set of puzzles includes only the blank grid then the set of corresponding solutions is vastly larger.

Comment: Note that if a corresponding puzzle has more than 1 solution, it is not possible to finish this puzzle.
You'll end up having to guess a solution, and this is not valid according to the rules.

Comment: @Heru-Luin, the question postulates that *the* puzzle may afford "solutions", plural.  That some do not consider a starting grid that affords multiple distinct solutions to be a valid Sudoku puzzle is beside the point.

Comment: You are right, it was just an additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a puzzle from a solution is very simple. You just apply the solving steps backwards.

For example, if a line contains 8 digits, you can fill in the 9th. If you do that backwards, if a line contains 9 digits, you can remove one. This will yield a very boring puzzle, but still a valid one (a valid puzzle is a puzzle with only one solution).

The more complicated the steps you make are, the more difficult the puzzle will be. In fact, brute forcing the puzzle is the most difficult strategy, executing it backwards probably boils down to randomly removing a digit, and brute force check if there is still only 1 unique solution. Notice you do not have to solve the entire puzzle: It's enough to prove there is only 1 way to add the removed digit back into the puzzle.

As for the second part of your question: This feels a bit like a mathematical question, but let me answer:

A good puzzle only has 1 solution. Since there are multiple puzzles that yield the same solution (like, there are 81 ways to fill in 80 of the 81 squares, all yielding the same solution from a different puzzle), you could say there are many more puzzles than solutions.

If you also allow puzzles with multiple solutions, it changes. For every puzzle, there must be one or more solutions, but all those solutions also belong to that puzzle, so the number of solutions to puzzles is equal to the number of puzzles to solutions. Invalid puzzles do not change this: Since they belong to 0 solutions, you need no additional puzzles belonging to those solutions.

Ps. It's also trivial to create puzzles if they do not need to be uniquely solvable: Just randomly remove some digits and you're done.